# how to use tap method instead of click method in appium?

Tags: android, selenium, appium, python-appium

I'm trying to automate an android test in appium and I have selected the webdriver as in wd/hub for this purpose. However, the tap method there is virtually the click method as all the auto-recorded steps are generated as clicks instead of tap / touch. I've tried to import TouchActions from selenium using the following command

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions import TouchActions
```

but python doesn't seem to recognize this command. I'm not sure if this command is deprecated. Any ideas anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `TouchAction(driver).tap(element).perform()` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Max but that only works in part. I'll have to manually edit each step from ```el.click()``` into ```TouchAction(driver).tap(element).perform()``` in this case since the code generated originally is still in click method. Is there a way to record steps directly as TouchAction instead of a click?

Comment: I've looked throw this code https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop, but not found the way, how to archive this. This might be not implemented. But I'm not 100% sure.